# Java Serialization with non serializable parts

Tags: java, serialization

I have:

```
class MyClass extends MyClass2 implements Serializable {
  //...
}
```

In MyClass2 is a property that is not serializable. How can I serialize (and de-serialize) this object?

Correction: MyClass2 is, of course, not an interface but a class.

Comment: Can you modify MyClass2 or not? Does the non-serializable property value need to be preserved by serialization?

The right approach depends on this.

Comment: MyClass2 could be modified. However, it would be better not to, since I build on top of it and it can be modified by others.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

As someone else noted, chapter 11 of Josh Bloch's [Effective Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683) is an indispensible resource on Java Serialization.

A couple points from that chapter pertinent to your question:

- assuming you want to serialize the state of the non-serializable field in MyClass2, that field must be accessible to MyClass, either directly or through getters and setters.  MyClass will have to implement custom serialization by providing readObject and writeObject methods.
- the non-serializable field's Class must have an API to allow getting it's state (for writing to the object stream) and then instantiating a new instance with that state (when later reading from the object stream.)
- per Item 74 of Effective Java, MyClass2 *must* have a no-arg constructor accessible to MyClass, otherwise it is impossible for MyClass to extend MyClass2 and implement Serializable.

I've written a quick example below illustrating this.

```
class MyClass extends MyClass2 implements Serializable{

  public MyClass(int quantity) {
    setNonSerializableProperty(new NonSerializableClass(quantity));
  }

  private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream out)
  throws IOException{
    // note, here we don't need out.defaultWriteObject(); because
    // MyClass has no other state to serialize
    out.writeInt(super.getNonSerializableProperty().getQuantity());
  }

  private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream in)
  throws IOException {
    // note, here we don't need in.defaultReadObject();
    // because MyClass has no other state to deserialize
    super.setNonSerializableProperty(new NonSerializableClass(in.readInt()));
  }
}

/* this class must have no-arg constructor accessible to MyClass */
class MyClass2 {

  /* this property must be gettable/settable by MyClass.  It cannot be final, therefore. */
  private NonSerializableClass nonSerializableProperty;

  public void setNonSerializableProperty(NonSerializableClass nonSerializableProperty) {
    this.nonSerializableProperty = nonSerializableProperty;
  }

  public NonSerializableClass getNonSerializableProperty() {
    return nonSerializableProperty;
  }
}

class NonSerializableClass{

  private final int quantity;

  public NonSerializableClass(int quantity){
    this.quantity = quantity;
  }

  public int getQuantity() {
    return quantity;
  }
}
```

Comment: Aww I was hoping for some kind of annotation like @NonSerialization :-/

Answer (score 36):

MyClass2 is just an interface so techinicaly it has no properties, only methods.  That being said if you have instance variables that are themselves not serializeable the only way I know of to get around it is to declare those fields transient.

ex:

```
private transient Foo foo;
```

When you declare a field transient it will be ignored during the serialization and deserialization process.  Keep in mind that when you deserialize an object with a transient field that field's value will always be it's default (usually null.)

Note you can also override the readResolve() method of your class in order to initialize transient fields based on other system state.

Answer (score 15):

If possible, the non-serialiable parts can be set as transient

```
private transient SomeClass myClz;
```

Otherwise you can use [Kryo](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo). Kryo is a fast and efficient object graph serialization framework for Java (e.g. JAVA serialization of java.awt.Color requires 170 bytes, Kryo only 4 bytes), which can serialize also non serializable objects. Kryo can also perform automatic deep and shallow copying/cloning. This is direct copying from object to object, not `object->bytes->object`.

Here is an example how to use kryo

```
Kryo kryo = new Kryo();
// #### Store to disk...
Output output = new Output(new FileOutputStream("file.bin"));
SomeClass someObject = ...
kryo.writeObject(output, someObject);
output.close();
// ### Restore from disk...
Input input = new Input(new FileInputStream("file.bin"));
SomeClass someObject = kryo.readObject(input, SomeClass.class);
input.close();
```

Serialized objects can be also compressed by registering exact serializer:

```
kryo.register(SomeObject.class, new DeflateCompressor(new FieldSerializer(kryo, SomeObject.class)));
```

Answer (score 11):

If you can modify MyClass2, the easiest way to address this is declare the property transient.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question - the question states MyClass2 contains the property that is not serializable, and ideally MyClass2 should not be modified.

Comment: You're right, I didn't read the question very carefully back when I answered it. I modified the answer.

Answer (score 6):

You will need to implement `writeObject()` and `readObject()` and do manual serialization/deserialization of those fields. See the javadoc page for `java.io.Serializable` for details. Josh Bloch's *Effective Java* also has some good chapters on implementing robust and secure serialization.

Answer (score 6):

Depends why that member of MyClass2 isn't serializable.

If there's some good reason why MyClass2 can't be represented in a serialized form, then chances are good the same reason applies to MyClass, since it's a subclass.

It may be possible to write a custom serialized form for MyClass by implementing readObject and writeObject, in such a way that the state of the MyClass2 instance data in MyClass can be suitably recreated from the serialized data. This would be the way to go if MyClass2's API is fixed and you can't add Serializable.

But first you should figure out why MyClass2 isn't serializable, and maybe change it.

Answer (score 5):

You can start by looking into the *transient* keyword, which marks fields as not part of the persistent state of an object.

Answer (score 5):

Several possibilities poped out and i resume them here:

- Implement writeObject() and readObject() as [sk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16399/sk) suggested
- declare the property transient and it won't be serialized as first stated by [hank](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7610/hank)
- use XStream as stated by [boris-terzic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1996/boris-terzic)
- use a Serial Proxy as stated by [tom-hawtin-tackline](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4725/tom-hawtin-tackline)

Answer (score 4):

[XStream](http://x-stream.github.io) is a great library for doing fast Java to XML serialization for any object no matter if it is Serializable or not. Even if the XML target format doesn't suit you, you can use the source code to learn how to do it.

Comment: hi, could you explain how to use XStream with a non serializable object ?

Comment: The Documentation is very self-explanatory, the tutorial starts with classes that do not implement Serializable and shows you how to serialize them: http://x-stream.github.io/tutorial.html

Answer (score 3):

A useful approach for serialising instances of non-serializable classes (or at least subclasses of) is known a Serial Proxy. Essentially you implement writeReplace to return an instance of a completely different serializable class which implements readResolve to return a copy of the original object. I wrote an example of serialising java.awt.BasicStroke on [Usenet](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.java.programmer/msg/820a7343ae7713a6)