# Non Serializable Objects - Networking

Tags: java, networking

I need to write a java program that sends objects over the network to a client program. The problem is that some of the objects that need to be sent are not serializable. How is this best tackled?

Comment: You might have your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/95181/java-serialization-with-non-serializable-parts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send the data needed to reconstruct the objects on the clientside.

Answer (score 1):

In enterprise world there is a special pattern [Transfer object pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfer_object_pattern). It suits your case ideally.