# Is there any way to get around a class not implementing Serializable?

Tags: java, serialization, plugins, minecraft, bukkit

Ok, so I use Bukkit's ItemStack in a HashMap that is stored in a file and reloaded from it, but I found out that org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_4_6.inventory.CraftMetaItem which is used in the hash map created by ItemStack.serialize() is not implementing Serializable. Is there some way to get around this? Thanks!

EDIT:

Here is a snippit of code from my plugin. It is the part that raises the error.

```
public void onEnable(
{
public Map<NewItem, List<ItemStack>> items = new HashMap<NewItem, List<ItemStack>>();
//Add content to items...
}
public void onDisable()
  {
      try
        {
          Map<List<Map<String, Object>>, NewItem> smap = new HashMap<List<Map<String, Object>>, NewItem>();
          for(NewItem item : items.keySet())
         {
              List<ItemStack> stacks = items.get(item);
                List<Map<String, Object>> stacks2 = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
              for(ItemStack stack : stacks)
              {
                  stacks2.add(stack.serialize());
                }
              smap.put(stacks2, item);
           }
          SaveLoadAPI.save(smap, this.getDataFolder().getPath()+"\\Items.data");
       }
      catch (Exception e)
        {
          getLogger().severe("Was unable to save the items file to the default path of: "+this.getDataFolder().getPath()+"\\Items.data");
            e.printStackTrace();
       }
  }
```

And here, last but certainly least, is the error!

```
16:08:52 [SEVERE] java.io.NotSerializableException: org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_4_
6.inventory.CraftMetaItem
16:08:52 [SEVERE]       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Sourc
e)
16:08:52 [SEVERE]       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source
)
16:08:52 [SEVERE]       at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(Unknown Source)
16:08:52 [SEVERE]       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native M
ethod)
16:08:52 [SEVERE]       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown S
ource)
16:08:52 [SEVERE]       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unkno
wn Source)
16:08:52 [SEVERE]       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
16:08:52 [SEVERE]       at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown S
ource)
16:08:52 [SEVERE]       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown So
urce)
16:08:52 [SEVERE]       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknow
n Source)
16:08:52 [SEVERE]       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Sourc
e)
16:08:52 [SEVERE]       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source
)
16:08:52 [SEVERE]       at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(Unknown Source)
16:08:52 [SEVERE]       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native M
ethod)
16:08:52 [SEVERE]       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown S
ource)
16:08:52 [SEVERE]       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unkno
wn Source)
16:08:52 [SEVERE]       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
16:08:52 [SEVERE]       at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown S
ource)
16:08:52 [SEVERE]       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown So
urce)
16:08:52 [SEVERE]       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknow
n Source)
16:08:52 [SEVERE]       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Sourc
e)
16:08:52 [SEVERE]       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source
)
16:08:52 [SEVERE]       at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(Unknown Source)
16:08:52 [SEVERE]       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native M
ethod)
16:08:52 [SEVERE]       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown S
ource)
16:08:52 [SEVERE]       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unkno
wn Source)
16:08:52 [SEVERE]       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
16:08:52 [SEVERE]       at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown S
ource)
16:08:52 [SEVERE]       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown So
urce)
16:08:52 [SEVERE]       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknow
n Source)
16:08:52 [SEVERE]       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Sourc
e)
16:08:52 [SEVERE]       at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source
)
16:08:52 [SEVERE]       at com.tommy3244.plugins.MakeYourOwnBlocks.SaveLoadAPI.s
ave(SaveLoadAPI.java:16)
16:08:52 [SEVERE]       at com.tommy3244.plugins.MakeYourOwnBlocks.MakeYourOwnBl
ocks.onDisable(MakeYourOwnBlocks.java:86)
16:08:52 [SEVERE]       at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlug
in.java:219)
16:08:52 [SEVERE]       at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.disablePlugin
(JavaPluginLoader.java:481)
16:08:52 [SEVERE]       at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.disablePlugin(S
implePluginManager.java:400)
16:08:52 [SEVERE]       at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.disablePlugins(
SimplePluginManager.java:393)
16:08:52 [SEVERE]       at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.clearPlugins(Si
mplePluginManager.java:434)
16:08:52 [SEVERE]       at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_4_6.CraftServer.reload(Craf
tServer.java:563)
16:08:52 [SEVERE]       at org.bukkit.Bukkit.reload(Bukkit.java:184)
16:08:52 [SEVERE]       at org.bukkit.command.defaults.ReloadCommand.execute(Rel
oadCommand.java:23)
16:08:52 [SEVERE]       at org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCo
mmandMap.java:186)
16:08:52 [SEVERE]       at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_4_6.CraftServer.dispatchCom
mand(CraftServer.java:514)
16:08:52 [SEVERE]       at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_4_6.CraftServer.dispatchSer
verCommand(CraftServer.java:506)
16:08:52 [SEVERE]       at net.minecraft.server.v1_4_6.DedicatedServer.al(Dedica
tedServer.java:260)
16:08:52 [SEVERE]       at net.minecraft.server.v1_4_6.DedicatedServer.r(Dedicat
edServer.java:225)
16:08:52 [SEVERE]       at net.minecraft.server.v1_4_6.MinecraftServer.q(Minecra
ftServer.java:494)
16:08:52 [SEVERE]       at net.minecraft.server.v1_4_6.MinecraftServer.run(Minec
raftServer.java:427)
16:08:52 [SEVERE]       at net.minecraft.server.v1_4_6.ThreadServerApplication.r
un(SourceFile:849)
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to serialize an object from a class from a third party library that doesn't implement the `Serializable` interface. If you're using this `org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_4_6.inventory.CraftMetaItem` in the class you need to serialize then mark it as `transient` in order to avoid the serialization of the object. If by any term you need to serialize it, then try making a child of this class and mark the child class as Serializable and use the child class in your object.

Comment: Tried making a child class....

Comment: Could you post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) of your actual code in order to get better guidance?

Answer (score 0):

check out this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95181/java-serialization-with-non-serializable-parts)

If you try to extends the class that is not serializable, all the fields you inherit (and the fields that are private) will not be serialized. So, unfortunately, extending a class with a lot of fields is not an option.

if the object org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_4_6.inventory.CraftMetaItem is a field you could marki it as transient to avoid serialization, and if that doesn't solve the problem you could try and implement the write() and read() methods. Check out the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) for more info.