# Serializing a class variable which does not implement serializable

Tags: java, serialization

I have a class which implements Serializable. There is an other class object in the class which does not implement serializable. What should be done to serialize the member of the class.

My class is something like this

```
public class Employee implements Serializable{
    private String name;
    private Address address;
}


public class Address{
    private String street; 
    private String area;   
    private String city;
}
```

Here, I dont have access to the Address class to make it implement Serializable. Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have to use Java's serialization?

Answer (score 6):

Well of course there's the obvious solution to put `Serializable` on it.  I understand that's not always an option.

Perhaps you can extend the `Address` and put `Serializable` on the child you make.  Then you make it so `Employee` has a `Child` field instead of an `Address` field.

Here are some other things to consider:

- You *can* keep the `Employee.address` field as an `Address` type.  You can serialize if you call the `Employee.setAddress(new SerializableAddress())`
- If `Address` is null, you can serialize the whole employee even if `Address`'s type is not serializable.
- If you mark `Address` as transient, it will skip trying to serialize `Address`.  This may solve your problem.

Then there are other "serialization" frameworks like [XStream](http://x-stream.github.io/) that don't require the marker interface to work.  It depends on your requirements whether that's an option though.

Comment: I would **not** extend it. The members are private anyway. Create a class `SerializeableAdress` which should be an exact copy of `Adress` and make it serializeable (of course...).

Comment: @mike They're private, but they're already `Serializable`.  Won't that be a non-issue?

Comment: Can we any other way except extending the address class??

Comment: You don't have access to private members if you extend a class.

Comment: @mike if it has getters and setters, it'll still work.  If it doesn't... how are you supposed to get data in there anyway?  And if you can't get data in there, then extending and using the child will serialize the same thing as if it originally implemented `Serializable `

Comment: Tried extending the address class but the private members!!!, I ll not be able to do that. Any other options please?

Comment: @user2047302 how do you set the data in there on a normal `Address`?

Comment: Could you please show some more code and more error messages.

Comment: @user2047302 then call the setters.  What's the problem?

Comment: And why are you not "able to do that" please show the error messages you get.

Answer (score 1):

You caanot directly make this Address class serializable as you do not have access to modify it.

There are few options :

- Create a subclass of Address class and use it. You can mark this class as serializable.
- Mark the Address as transient.

Please take a look at this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95181/java-serialization-with-non-serializable-parts) link

Comment: Also this class is being used in many others logics. If I have to create a new class that is exactly same I ll have to rewrite so many parts of the app.

Comment: You can simply inherit this class without overriding any of the methods in it. It will be as good as base class.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the option to use a 3rd party library for serialization, then you can use for example [kryo](https://code.google.com/p/kryo/). This has a default serialization which doesn't require implementing interfaces or annotating fields.

You can check [Which is the best alternative for Java Serialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239280/which-is-the-best-alternative-for-java-serialization) for more alternatives.