# Saving HashMap with FileOutputStream

Tags: java, serialization, fileoutputstream

I'm trying to write a HashMap with the FileOutputStream. 
This is what my code looks like.

```
    public class ObjectStream implements Serializable{
        public void serialize(HashMap<String, Mat> obj){
            try {
                FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\Juergen\\fileoutputstream.txt");
                ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutput);
                out.write(obj);
                out.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 

        }
}
```

The Problem is that the "write" function is not applicable for the argument. What can i do?Thanks

Comment: Have you tried writeObject() method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to the previous answers, it has to be additionaly mention, that the `Mat` class originates from OpenCV. According to its Javadoc, it does not implement the `Serializable` interface. Thus, it will not be properly serializable via object serialization in Java.

Basically you can use a third-party object serialization library, which supports serialization without implementing `Serializable`. Related: [Serializing a class, which does not implement Serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18643115/serializing-a-class-variable-which-does-not-implement-serializable)

An other way to persist your data would be to implement your own custom file format in `CSV` or `XML`. For example:

```
key1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

key2
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

This can be easily parsed / written using Apache Commons IO classes or JDK basic file io.

Comment: i would like to use JSON, do i need to format the object or can i just give it to json and let it do the serialization for me?

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7539954/java-json-serialization-best-practice

Answer (score 1):

Use the writeObject() method instead of the write() method:

```
out.writeObject(obj);
```

Comment: Yes i have. The problem is that when i load the data with the FileInputReader the same wait, it is not the same any more. So i get a floating point matrix exception that i don't get for the matrix before saving

Comment: Is your matrix implements Serializable?

Comment: Implementing Serializable is mandatory to use object serialization. I suggest to write it out in a custom file-format (like csv or xml)

Answer (score 1):

If you use `ObjectOutputStream` to serialize your data, it's important that you call the correct `write*()` method depending on the type of data you want to store. See the [JavaDoc for `ObjectOutputStream.writeObject()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#writeObject(java.lang.Object))

```
        try {
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\Juergen\\fileoutputstream.txt");
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutput);
            out.writeObject(obj); //Writes an Object!
            out.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```