# SonarQube giving a "Fields in a "Serializable" class should either be transient or serializable" when class is serializable?

Tags: java, sonarqube

```
public class ClassName implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private Map<String, Object> variableName;
```

In the above code, the sonarQube is giving CRITICAL level issue because of variableName. I know Object is not serializable but do anyone have any solution to avoid or resolve this issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java Serialization with non serializable parts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95181/java-serialization-with-non-serializable-parts)

Comment: Not all implementations of `Map` are `Serializable`; also, not all `Object`s are serializable. Change `Map` and `Object` to something that are serializable.

Comment: @AndyTurner any suggestion. Change Map and Object to what?

Comment: @jeprubio let me implement it. I still have doubts on this how it's working

Comment: @Moeezalikhan for example `HashMap` is serializable, provided its keys and values are serializable. As for an alternative to `Object`: it entirely depends what you're trying to store.